# Trouble Rotating 3D Cube in OpenGL and Pygame

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, pygame

I am trying to create a 3D cube in OpenGL and Pygame. I want the cube to rotate when you hold down a button. However, right now the cube only rotates when you press a button rather than holding. Can someone help me with this issue? Thanks!

```
def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (800, 600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

    gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)

    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)
    glRotatef(45, 1, 1, 0)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  # checking pressed keys
            if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                glRotatef(5, 1, 0, 0)
            if keys[pygame.K_s]:
                glRotatef(5, 0, 1, 0)
            if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                glRotatef(5, 0, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your key handling code is within the `for` loop. Hence, if there is no event, you will not handle the keys. Move the code outside of the loop:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  # checking pressed keys
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        glRotatef(5, 1, 0, 0)
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        glRotatef(5, 0, 1, 0)
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        glRotatef(5, 0, 0, 1)
```